# Formatting String Digits in Python Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame which has 3 digits (string) such as '001' , '010' and '121'. I would like to replace any 1 digit and any 2 digit strings such as '001' , and '010' with just '1' and '10'.

How can I do this? I tried using the apply method (see below) but nothing changes.

`df.ZIPCOUNTY_CA` is the pandas dataframe and `'county code'` is the column which has these string digits.

```
df_ZIPCOUNTY_CA[df_ZIPCOUNTY_CA['county code'].str.startswith('0')]['county codes'] = df_ZIPCOUNTY_CA[df_ZIPCOUNTY_CA['county code'].str.startswith('0')]['county code'].apply(lambda x: x.split('0')[1])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or use `str.replace` to remove leading zeros:

```
df_ZIPCOUNTY_CA['county code']

#0    010
#1    001
#2    121
#Name: county code, dtype: object

df_ZIPCOUNTY_CA['county code'].str.replace('^0+', '')

#0     10
#1      1
#2    121
#Name: county code, dtype: object
```

`^0+` is a regular expression; `^` matches the beginning of string, `0` matches literal `0`, and `+` is quantifier stands for one or more; Together `^0+` matches all zeros that starts from the beginning of string.

Here is a little timing about the two approaches.

```
df_ZIPCOUNTY_CA = pd.DataFrame([['010'], ['001'], ['121']], columns=['county code'])
​
df_ZIPCOUNTY_CA = pd.concat([df_ZIPCOUNTY_CA] * 10000)

%timeit df_ZIPCOUNTY_CA['county code'].str.replace('^0+', '')
# 10 loops, best of 3: 37.1 ms per loop

%timeit df_ZIPCOUNTY_CA['county code'].astype(int).astype(str)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 70.8 ms per loop
```

Or as @Bill commented, might just use `str.lstrip`, the fastest approach here:

```
%timeit df_ZIPCOUNTY_CA['county code'].str.lstrip('0')
# 100 loops, best of 3: 8.9 ms per loop

# added the map str approach for comparison as well
%timeit df_ZIPCOUNTY_CA['county code'].astype(int).map(str)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 13.3 ms per loop
```

Comment: thank you. Can you please let me know what '^0+' is and where I can learn more about it?

Comment: Explanation added. You can look into the [regex info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) if you want to learn more about regex.

Comment: Would be simpler to use `str.lstrip()` no?

Comment: @Bill Yes, you are right. That could be the best approach here.

Comment: Found the list`[x.lstrip('0') for x in df.A]` is the fastest so far,

Comment: @Wen Good find. Another smell that `pandas` and `numpy` are not optimized for string operations.

Comment: @Psidom yep , it is true :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your series to `int` and then to `str`.

```
df_ZIPCOUNTY_CA['county code'] = df_ZIPCOUNTY_CA['county code'].astype(int).astype(str)
```

**Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['001', '010', '100']})

df['A'] = df['A'].astype(int).map(str)

print(df)

#      A
# 0    1
# 1   10
# 2  100
```

**Performance benchmarking**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['001', '010', '100']})

df = pd.concat([df]*10000, ignore_index=True)

%timeit df['A'].astype(int).map(str)    # 21.6 ms
%timeit df['A'].str.replace('^0+', '')  # 77.2 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

BY using `to_numeric`

```
pd.to_numeric(df.A)
Out[66]: 
0      1
1     10
2    100
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Or using `lstrip` in python (not pandas `str.lstrip`)

```
[x.lstrip('0') for x in df.A]
```

Timing : the loop is faster ??...

```
%timeit [x.lstrip('0') for x in df.A]
100 loops, best of 3: 5.26 ms per loop
%timeit df['A'].str.lstrip('0')
100 loops, best of 3: 10 ms per loop
```